Replace Leaking Y Junction Cleanout From Washer Drain Before Main Sewer Line
I found a leak in the Y junction which is a cleanout for my washer drain right before it joins the main. I'm pretty certain that there is a clog in the main further down because the water squirts out of the cleanout like a water fountain for a while after the washing machine stops draining. I can fix the clog.
How do I repair this leak? It's leaking only from the coupling on the base of the Y junction cleanout, not from the Y junction connecting to the main. I can cut out the Y just fine. There's enough pipe coming off the Y from the main to join it to the new Y. For the line coming from the washer, do I cut it shorter to fit a coupling and then another pipe to join the new cleanout?


Repair complete. I had enough wiggle room to use hard lines on both sides of the wye.


You will need to get the following:

ABS glue/cement
ABS coupling
ABS wye or line cleanout
short piece of ABS pipe (some box stores sell 2 foot sections)
rubber coupling with gear clamps (fernco)


What to do:

cut two 6" long pieces from the new pipe
glue both the pieces into the two ends of the wye (or line cleanout)
measure the length of the glued assembly
mark out this distance on the existing pipe (add about 1/2") and cut out the existing section
slide the rubber coupling over the downstream end of the existing pipe
glue the coupling onto the upstream end of the existing pipe
glue the new assembly into the coupling
slide the rubber coupling over the down stream joint and tighten the gear clamps


Confirmed that it's ABS

Have an extra ABS coupling on hand. The pipes appear to be in an area where they're relatively free to move and it could turn out that the pipes can be pushed apart enough to admit use of two ABS couplings rather than one ABS and one rubber. If it's necessary to use the rubber coupling, and if the pipes are not well-supported, you may do well to choose one that is shielded (has a metal supporting band around it) to support the weight and avoid shear/sagging at the rubber coupler.

lets give you some points for nice post

Thanks @GregHill for the extra coupling suggestion. I had enough play to avoid the rubber coupler.

Thanks @pdd for the parts list and excellent instructions.
